# How can I add more than four disk images to qemu?

Tags: linux, virtual-machine, kvm, qemu

Qemu fails when I try to add more than 4 disk images using `-drive file=...,index={0..3},media=disk,format=raw`. The error I get for each additional drive is similar to the following:

```
qemu-system: -drive ....: machine type does not support if=ide,bus=2,unit=X
```

How do get qemu to accept additional drives?

Answer (score 5):

KVM can currently only virtualize [four IDE drives](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/5/html/virtualization/sect-virtualization-virtualization_limitations-kvm_limitations) for a given guest. The `-drive` option defaults to IDE drives if the interface type is not explicitly stated.

If you're not particularly attached to IDE virtualization, you can add more than 4 drives to your virtual machine by attaching them as virtio drives (i.e by adding `if=virtio` to your `-drive` options):

```
-drive file=...,if=virtio,index=X,...
```

Keep in mind that

1. your guest must include support for virtio drives (most modern linux distributions do)
2. your drives will appear as `vdx` instead of `sdx`, so make sure you update your guest's grub/commandline/fstab if the guest already exisits
3. if your distribution does not include the necessary drivers in your initramfs (most do) and your root filesystem is on a virtio drive, you'll have to add them (e.g. to `/etc/initramfs-tools/modules`) and rebuild it yourself (i.e. `update-initramfs -u`). That, or you could just add the root drive as a normal IDE drive.

See `qemu-system(1)` for more information.

**A note about deprecation:** The [deprecation of SCSI passthrough on `virtio-blk` devices](https://www.qemu.org/docs/master/system/deprecated.html) does not effect other aspects of virtio. In fact, as of this writing, the virtio interface remains the [recommended way](https://www.linux-kvm.org/page/Tuning_KVM) to use disk images with KVM.

Comment: It seems this will use virtio-blk, which is considered very deprecated (and has its own limits, due to requiring one PCI device per image). Do you have an example for doing the same using virtio-scsi?

Comment: Hey, @user1686. I'm having difficulty locating anything that documents the deprecation of virtio interfaces in either qemu or KVM. The closest I've found is [the deprecation of SCSI passthrough](https://www.qemu.org/docs/master/system/deprecated.html) in `virtio-blk`, which does not apply to virtio drives as a whole. Please do correct me if I'm wrong.